# Angular2: http.get returns "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Tags: c#, web, angular, cors, owin

I'm getting the following error:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

when making the following request to my web api from my angular2 app:

```
     return this.http.get("http://localhost/api/test", { headers })
    .map(res => this.extractData(res))
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Some considerations:

- I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Cors
- Requests work fine when they don't include headers. This one includes headers for authentication purposes.
- I can make the request using Chrome.
- Microsoft.Owin.Cors is installed in the solution
- `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` is at the start of the configuration method of startup.cs

The following is included in the web.config file:

```
 <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionControllerv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you don't configure preflight requests on the server side (for OPTIONS methods).

There are two kinds of requests with CORS:

- **Simple requests**. This use case applies if we use HTTP GET, HEAD and POST methods. In the case of POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: text/plain, application/x-www-form-urlencoded and multipart/form-data.
- **Preflighted requests**. When the ‘simple requests’ use case doesn’t apply, a first request (with the HTTP OPTIONS method) is made to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

When adding headers, you switch from simple to preflight requests. So an OPTIONS request is executed under the hood before the target request.

See this article for more details:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/

Comment: They mention that the issue is that the server doesn't include headers in the response of a prefligthed request, but they don't mention how to it? also, I thought app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); would take care of that?

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to `webapiconfig.cs` file

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("", "", "*"); 
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

you can do one more thing in `ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs` add this line in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
```

Comment: I think that's for Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and I'm using Microsoft.Owin.Cors. Sorry for leaving that detail out. I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: i am using System.Web.Http.Cors;ok